# Karaf private repository: unauthorized

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I'm using private corporate maven repository, configured (together with credentials) in my `settings.xml` .

However, when I've started Karaf with empty repository cache, I've got failures that the artifacts couldn't be found. Karaf has only checked the repositories listed in `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg`.

When I've added my repository to the list, I've go the error 'Not authorized'. It looks like Karaf is ignoring my `settings.xml`.

How to use artifacts from the private repository using Karaf?

I'm using Karaf 4.2.8 and Maven 3.8.1

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to install maven with `feature:install maven` and then add your repository like this `maven:repository-add -id your_id -u your_username -p your_password   your_url` you can also add -s if it's a snapshots repository